# How to use formatted print for displaying UTF-8 in Haskell for CGI?

Tags: haskell, utf-8, cgi, printf

I have a code

```
module Main where

import Text.Printf

main = printf "%s%s" ("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n" :: String ) ("And немного русского" :: String)
```

And if I execute it in terminal, I have what I want:

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8

And немного русского
```

But when I try to execute it as cgi-program, I have just `And` (because after this word I have cyrillic characters and they are do not want to be displayed).

There is no problems, when I use `putStr $ fromString` from `Data.ByteString.Char8` and `Data.ByteString.UTF8`, so I don't think that there is a problem with my LAMPP server. And I also included `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` in httpd.conf.

And exactly what I want to do is to read a template file with special symbols such as `%s`, `%d` etc., and then, with the help of `printf`, replace them (symbols) with that what I need, depending on query string and display.

I do it just for fun and I want this problem solved only with pure Haskell.

Comment: Check the locale your Apache server runs in. I imagine the deaktop environment has `*.utf-8`.

Comment: For a quick check you can run a CGI script that just executes the `locale` command.

Comment: I have this list:

LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=

Comment: That was expected. Haskell IO tries to use the encoding of your locale, which would be ASCII in the case of POSIX locale. ASCII has no cyrillic characters, so they are just skipped on output. You can try to force a UTF8 locale on your CGI program (if you have any installed on your LAMP server), by setting the LANG environment variable (use mod_env in Apache). Or you can `printf` to a string and output that string with e.g. `System.IO.UTF8`, no locale manipulations needed.

Comment: I'm quite sure the correct way to add an answer to your own question on SO is simply to add it as an actual answer. And instead of changing the title to include the word resolved, you should accept the answer that bests solves your problem. Then the answer count becomes yellow, so people can see that the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very good solution is to set environmental variable LANG in httpd.conf, .htaccess or httpd-vhosts.conf (in LAMPP) by putting the string `SetEnv LANG en_US.UTF-8` in one of these files.

In httpd.conf you can set this variable for all server.

For setting it with .htaccess file, you must enable this opportunity in vhosts.conf

```
<Directory "<.htaccess directory>">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

And then you'll be able to change variables with .htaccess file in set directory by using SetEnv.

In vhosts.conf you can just add string `SetEnv LANG en_US.UTF-8` within `VirtualHost` block.

This solution allow you to use UTF-8 and others without libraries such as Data.ByteString.Char8.

And again thank you n.m.!

Answer (score 7):

It may or may not be appropriate to have the CGI program depend on the locale; e.g. if your generated HTML has an encoding header saying it is UTF-8, then you should generate UTF-8 independently of your systems locale.

A locale-independent way is to set the encoding of stdout before you print anything to it:

```
import System.IO

main = do
    hSetEncoding stdout utf8
    printf "%s%s" ("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n" :: String ) ("And немного русского" :: String)
```

Your code:

```
/tmp $ echo $LANG
de_DE.utf8
/tmp $ ./Test2
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8

And немного русского
/tmp $ LANG=C ./Test2 
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8

And Test2: <stdout>: commitBuffer: invalid argument (invalid character)
```

Modified code:

```
/tmp $ ./Test2
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8

And немного русского
/tmp $ LANG=C ./Test2 
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8

And немного русского
```

Comment: This us much better than my advice. I forgot completely about `hSetEncoding` :-(